# How is parsing a word of a formal language wrt its formal grammar defined?

Tags: formal-languages

1. About  [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) from Wikipedia:

   > In computer science and linguistics, parsing, or, more formally,
   >   syntactic analysis, is the process of analyzing a text, made of a
   >   sequence of tokens (for example, words), to determine its grammatical
   >   structure with respect to a given (more or less) formal grammar.

   Is there a formal definition, or a more clear one, for parsing a
   word of a formal language wrt its formal grammar defined?  I am not
   able to understand the meaning of parsing, because I am stuck at the
   term "grammatical structure" of a word wrt the formal grammar.
2. About [analytic grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Analytic_grammars) and parsing from Wikipedia:

   > Though there is a tremendous body of literature on **parsing
   >   algorithms**, most of these algorithms assume that the language to be
   >   parsed is initially described by means of a **generative formal
   >   grammar**, and that the goal is to transform this generative grammar
   >   into **a working parser**. Strictly speaking, a generative grammar
   >   does not in any way correspond to the algorithm used to parse a
   >   language, and various algorithms have different restrictions on the
   >   form of production rules that are considered well-formed.
   >
   > An alternative approach is to formalize the language in terms of an
   >   **analytic grammar** in the first place, which more directly corresponds to the structure and semantics of a parser for the
   >   language.

   What do "generative grammar" and "analytic grammar" mean?

   Isn't that true that formal grammars are always "generative" in the
   sense that they generate formal languages?

Thanks and regards!